# Console Application Failed to Retrieve Data With Wcf Service

Tags: c#, wcf, console-application

I am consuming wcf service into console application . I am trying to retrieve account information based on account number . But the problem is when i enter the account number and hit enter ,its only displaying account number and rest of the fields are empty.

Here is the base class.

```
[DataContract]
    public class Current_Account_Details
    { 
    string account_creation_date;
    string account_type;
    string branch_sort_code;
    string account_fees;
    string account_balance;
    string over_draft_limit;
    string  account_holder_id;

    [DataMember]
    public string Account_Creation_Date
    {
        get { return account_creation_date; }
        set { account_creation_date = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string Account_Type
    {
        get { return account_type; }
        set { account_type = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string Branch_Sort_Code
    {
        get { return branch_sort_code; }
        set { branch_sort_code = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string Account_Fees
    {
        get { return account_fees; }
        set { account_fees = value; }

    }
    [DataMember]
    public string Account_Balance
    {
        get { return account_balance; }
        set { account_balance = value; }


    }
    [DataMember]
    public string Over_Draft_Limit
    {

        get { return over_draft_limit; }
        set { over_draft_limit = value; }

    }
    [DataMember]
    public string Account_Holder_Id
    {

        get { return account_holder_id; }
        set { account_holder_id = value; }
    }
}
}
```

Here is the inherited class.

```
 [DataContract]
    public class AccountBalanceRequest : Current_Account_Details
    {
        string account_number;

        [DataMember]
        public string Account_Number
        {
            get { return account_number; }
            set { account_number = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Interface .

```
 [OperationContract]
        AccountBalanceRequest AccountBalanceCheek(AccountBalanceRequest accountNumber);
```

Here is my Method .

```
public AccountBalanceRequest AccountBalanceCheek(AccountBalanceRequest accountNumber)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            //use top 1 since you are only getting one record.
            //let us use string interpolation, if you are working below C#6
            //replace it with your previous value
            var cmd = new SqlCommand($@"SELECT TOP 1
                                            * 
                                        FROM 
                                            Current_Account_Details 
                                        WHERE 
                                            Account_Number ='{accountNumber.Account_Number}'", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            //use ExecuteReader to execute sql select
            //ExecuteNonQuery is for update, delete, and insert.
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            //read the result of the execute command.
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //assuming that your property is the same as your table schema. refer to your table schema Current_Account_Details
                //assuming that your datatype are string... just do the conversion...
                accountNumber.Account_Balance = reader["Account_Balance"].ToString();
                accountNumber.Account_Fees = reader["Account_Fees"].ToString();
                accountNumber.Account_Balance = reader["Account_Balance"].ToString();
                accountNumber.Over_Draft_Limit = reader["Over_Draft_Limit"].ToString();
            }
            return accountNumber;
        }

    }
```

Here is the code in Console Application .

```
     public static void Balance()
    {
        MyService.HalifaxCurrentAccountServiceClient currentAccount = new MyService.HalifaxCurrentAccountServiceClient("NetTcpBinding_IHalifaxCurrentAccountService");
        MyService.AccountBalanceRequest cs = new MyService.AccountBalanceRequest();

        string AccountNumber;


        Console.WriteLine("\nEnter your Account Number--------:");
        AccountNumber = Console.ReadLine();
        cs.Account_Number = AccountNumber;
        // MyService.AccountBalanceRequest cs1 = currentAccount.AccountBalanceCheek(AccountNumber);



        MyService.AccountBalanceRequest AccountBalance = currentAccount.AccountBalanceCheek(cs);//error on this line

               Console.WriteLine("Account Number is :" + cs.Account_Number);
                Console.WriteLine("Account creation date  :" + cs.Account_Creation_Date);

                Console.WriteLine("Account Type :" + cs.Account_Type);
                Console.WriteLine("Branch_Sort_Code:" + cs.Branch_Sort_Code);
                Console.WriteLine("Account_Fee:" + cs.Account_Fees);
                Console.WriteLine("Account Account_Balance :" + cs.Account_Balance);
                Console.WriteLine("Account Over Draft Limit :" + cs.Over_Draft_Limit);


            Console.Write("--------------------------");
                Console.ReadLine();
                //Console.Clear();


       }
```

Here is the screen shot of the database.[click here to record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGugZ.png)
Here is the screen shot when i run the application[Click here to see the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtMuu.png).**In this screen shot only the account number is displaying and rest of the fields are empty**

Comment: Two things. 1. Double check your column names and post the class definition. 2. Before you get into any bad habits, don't ever, ever, ever, ever concatenate user input into sql queries. It's called [SQL injection](https://xkcd.com/327/) and it's bad news.

Comment: where is operation contract ?

Comment: kindly post that also its implementation so that we have clear picture of your intention and where it is failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your **Current_Account_Details** is the base class  and **AccountBalanceRequest**  is derived class from your question posted.

If we have classes related by inheritance, the wcf service generally accepts and returns the base type. If you expect the service to accept and return inherited types, then use **KnownType** attribute.
So its enough if you decorate the base class with contracts and try.

```
[KnownType(typeof(AccountBalanceRequest))]
[DataContract]
    public class Current_Account_Details
    { 
    string account_creation_date;
    string account_type;
    string branch_sort_code;
    string account_fees;
    string account_balance;
    string over_draft_limit;
    string  account_holder_id;

    [DataMember]
    public string Account_Creation_Date
    {
        get { return account_creation_date; }
        set { account_creation_date = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string Account_Type
    {
        get { return account_type; }
        set { account_type = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string Branch_Sort_Code
    {
        get { return branch_sort_code; }
        set { branch_sort_code = value; }
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string Account_Fees
    {
        get { return account_fees; }
        set { account_fees = value; }

    }
    [DataMember]
    public string Account_Balance
    {
        get { return account_balance; }
        set { account_balance = value; }


    }
    [DataMember]
    public string Over_Draft_Limit
    {

        get { return over_draft_limit; }
        set { over_draft_limit = value; }

    }
    [DataMember]
    public string Account_Holder_Id
    {

        get { return account_holder_id; }
        set { account_holder_id = value; }
    }
}
}
 public class AccountBalanceRequest : Current_Account_Details
    {
        string account_number;
              public string Account_Number
        {
            get { return account_number; }
            set { account_number = value; }
        }
    }
```

Just check whether account number that you read from console is passed in the accountnumber variable.

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Current_Account_Details WHERE Account_Number = '" + accountNumber + "'", conn);
```

**Edit 1**: Your service is failing to retrieve records because you are passing the AccountBalanceRequest object and the changes made to the object is not reflected outside the method.

```
 MyService.AccountBalanceRequest cs = new MyService.AccountBalanceRequest();
```

Change it to.

```
     public AccountBalanceRequest AccountBalanceCheek(AccountBalanceRequest accountNumber)
            {
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                //use top 1 since you are only getting one record.
                //let us use string interpolation, if you are working below C#6
                //replace it with your previous value
                var cmd = new SqlCommand($@"SELECT TOP 1
                                                * 
                                            FROM 
                                                Current_Account_Details 
                                            WHERE 
                                                Account_Number ='{accountNumber.Account_Number}'", conn));
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                //use ExecuteReader to execute sql select
                //ExecuteNonQuery is for update, delete, and insert.
                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                //read the result of the execute command.
                while(reader.Read())
                {
                    //assuming that your property is the same as your table schema. refer to your table schema Current_Account_Details
                   //assuming that your datatype are string... just do the conversion...
                    accountNumber.Account_Balance = reader["Account_Balance"].ToString();
                    accountNumber.Account_Fee = reader["Account_Fee"].ToString();
                    accountNumber.Account_Balance = reader["Account_Balance"].ToString();
                    accountNumber.Over_Draft_Limit = reader["Over_Draft_Limit"].ToString();
                }
                return accountNumber;
            }
        }
```

In your console retrieve it,

```
MyService.AccountBalanceRequest AccountBalance =currentAccount.AccountBalanceCheek(cs);
  Console.WriteLine("Your Account Number is :" + cs.Account_Number)
  ...
```

Comment: When you put a debugger, is the control entering inside the while loop?

Comment: Thanks you very much for your help and support

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you're passing a reference to the WCF service method and changing it there instead of returning. The documentation says that:

> Each operation has a return value and a parameter, even if these are void. However, unlike a local method, in which you can pass references to objects from one object to another, **service operations do not pass references to objects. Instead, they pass copies of the objects**.

Try to change your code so the method returns the changed object. At the end of AccountBalanceCheek method instead of returning *true* return *accountNumber*.

And then in Balance method - remove if statement and change to:

```
....
cs = currentAccount.AccountBalanceCheek(cs);
Console.WriteLine("Your Account Number is :" + cs.Account_Number);
Console.WriteLine("Your Account Type :" + cs.Account_Balance);
....
```

To read more about it: [Is it possible to pass parameters by reference with WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24307882/is-it-possible-to-pass-parameters-by-reference-with-wcf)